# Can't enumerate UNC path in VBA with dir over a VPN

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, vpn

I have a macro that takes xml files from a network share, gets the data out and formats a document then saves it as a PDF back to the network.  This has been working fine for a few years now, but with the current work from home surge I'm getting errors when the macro tries to dir() the network share and the user is connected with a VPN.

I have fully qualified the server name (using UNC) and checked that the computers can see the share directly, but VBA just fails.

Is there a way to get the dir() command to see UNC paths over a VPN, or perhaps another way to enumerating the remote folder and reading the files.

Comment: You can try using `FileSystemObject` if you don't need to support Macs

Comment: Thanks, I only have a Mac at home, but I can get a pc user to test this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a VPN, and I don't have access to any kind of UNC now, so I can't test anything, but but I think You can set a UNC to **include the host IP address directly**, for example:

```
\\192.168.1.42\Your_Target_File\Text.xlsx
```